# jQuery Datatable multiselect not working in page 2 with pagination

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am using datatables for my application, multiselect is working in first page but it seems not working with pages 2 and 3 with pagination.

Code is,

```
    $(document).ready(function() {   
        $('#example tr').click( function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('row_selected');
        } );    
    } );
```

and css is

```
table.display tr.even.row_selected td {
background-color: #efefef;
}

table.display tr.odd.row_selected td {
background-color: #efefef;
}
```

what else should i include to make multiselect work for other pages? 
Or is there anything wrong with the code?

Please help

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 Things..

1.Make sure to include the js code in your page 2 and a page 3

2.May be your `tr` are generated dynamically..you need to `delegate`

```
 $(document).ready(function() {   
        $('#example').delegate('tr','click', function() { //example -> tableid
            $(this).toggleClass('row_selected');
        } );    
    } );
```

Answer (score 1):

You are dynamically modifying the dom so you need to delegate either with .delegate or .on if using jQuery 1.7+

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $('#example').on('click','tr', function() { 
        $(this).toggleClass('row_selected');
    } );    
});
```

or if using jQuery 1.6 and lower

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $('#example').delegate('tr', 'click', function() { 
        $(this).toggleClass('row_selected');
    } );    
});
```

By delegating you bind the event handler to a parent element.. it then listens for when the event bubbles up.. for example when you click on a tr... it bubbles up the the `document` in this example then the document handles the event..

If you try and bind it the regular way

ex

```
$('tr').click()function(){});
```

or

```
$('tr').bind('click',function(){});
```

or

```
$('tr').on('click',function(){});
```

They expect the tr element to be available at the time the dom is ready - (if you put your code inside a document.ready function) - or else no events will be bound to the element